# A "Schwartz function" of Schwartz function?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, functional-analysis, probability-distributions, schwartz-space

Let $f_1:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ be a Schwartz function, and $\mathcal S(\mathbb R)$ be the space of Schwartz functions (Schwartz space). $\mathcal B(\mathcal S)$ is the Borel $\sigma$-field of $\mathcal S$. Let $f_2: \mathcal S(\mathbb R)\to\mathbb R$ be a function-valued function, something like (not formal since if I know how to formally write this, I won't be asking this question):

$$\sup_{f_1\in\mathcal S_1(\mathbb R)}(1+|f_1|)^m|Df_2|<\infty \ \ \forall m\in\mathbb N$$

Let's call this a "Schwartz function" of Schwartz function, and denote the space as $\mathcal S_2(\mathbb R)=\mathcal S(\mathcal S(\mathbb R))$.

The questions are

1. Are there any works done related to this?
2. How to rigorously define a topology and measure over $\mathcal S_n(\mathbb R)$ ?

---

Some mathematicians said that it is related to Hida distributions, Kondratiev triple, Borchers algebra, and quantum field theory.

Comment: When you say "Let $f_1$ be a Scwhartz distribution", do you really mean "Let $f_1$ be a function such that $g \mapsto \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_1(x) g(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$ is a tempered distribution"? Or are you merely using an unusual name for a Schwartz function? Since you call $S(\mathbb{R})$ the [Schwartz space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space), I assume the latter. Normally we don't call them distributions.

Comment: @Hurkyl updated

Comment: @dodo: Despite the upvotes, your question is still flawed. The "Schwartz space" is not the space of Schwartz distributions, but the space of Schwartz functions. The notation for it $\mathcal S$, while the dual is $\mathcal S'$. Furthermore, Borel subsets have no place here. It seems that you are mistaking the term "distribution" from probability theory with the term "distribution" from distribution theory: there is no connection whatsoever between them. You'd better learn the basics of distribution theory before attempting to advance to more complicated subjects.

Comment: @AlexM. The probability distribution is formally defined by distribution (the generalized functions). For example, Dirac delta is not a function but it is a probability distribution. Thanks for the clarifications; I changed the notations.